# jQuery UI datepicker age validation

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am making a dating website so I want people only above 18 years of age to join. I am using jQuery UI datepicker. I want that the YEAR section shows 18 years less (1997) instead of current year (2016) so that people only above age of 18 can join the system. And every new year it shifts like maximum year selection will be 1998 next year and 1999 the 2nd year and so on.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Provide `minDate` which will be derived from something like `current date - date to have minimum 18 years`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker(
    {
      minDate: new Date(1900,1-1,1), maxDate: '-18Y',
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      yearRange: '-110:-18'
    }
  );                    
});
```

Comment: is defaultDate really necessary? I commented it out and still getting default date as 1998..

Comment: Its not neccessary ... if yu want to give then u can specify

Comment: i think removing it is better.. I am already getting 18 years less and default as 1998 so nothing else more needed now.. please edit your answer removing the default date and I am accepting it ok :)

Answer (score 0):

I think (but am not sure without seeing the HTML) that you need to provide a value within the input-field like this:

`<input name="date" id="datepicker" value="97-01-01" />`

Answer (score 0):

Hullo, worked on a system that required age validation once. I made use of [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/). In my code I have something like;

```
var dateOfBirth = Date.parse('1992-01-01'); // can be any date
var minimumDateOfBirth = Date.today().add(-18).years();
isRightAge = !(Date.compare(dateOfBirth, minimumDateOfBirth) > 0);
```